# Android fail to use best ressources

Tags: android, xml, resolution, hdpi

I created a folder layout-xhdpi for particular XML for these kind of screen.

So I've the layout folder, and layout-xhdpi folder.

But when I launch the application on a phone HDPI, he gets the XML which are in layout-xhdpi folder.

I don't understand why, i missed something to do ?

Thx,

Comment: I guess you have to create `layout-hdpi` for phone with HDPI density

Comment: oh no..; seriously ? Android doesn't take automatically the best ressources ? The default folder is layout..

Comment: I have tried once, if you have XMLs in `layout` folder (alone) `hdpi` and `xhdpi` takes `layout` folder. But specifying `layout-xhdpi` folders and xmls it forced me to create `layout-hdpi` for supporting HDPI density

Comment: Check you have the resource in the layout-hdpi folder as well, and ensure it is named *exactly* the same as the one in xhdpi.

Comment: So, I need to create a folder for each resolution ? Because the app need to run to in mdpi, ldpi etc...

Comment: for your question create `layout-hdpi` folder and copy the xmls from `layout` to `layout-hdpi` it should work.

Comment: Using density qualifiers (e.g., `-hdpi`) for anything other than a `drawable` resource directory is a serious code smell. It is almost guaranteed that you will not get what you want.

Comment: But why ? I didn't read this on the developer documentation.